# How to get the Activities of a Workflow from within the rehosted WorkflowDesigner

Tags: c#, android-activity, workflow-foundation, workflow-rehosting

In a rehosted workflow,  if I do have a variable of type of my WorkflowDesigner, and I create a workflow within it (from the UI), how do I get the list of the activities later programmatically?

so the input is the instance of my WorkflowDesigner , the desired output is programmatically get the list of the activities within a workflow in C# of course.

I would take any book, any URl , any hints.  I am so confused between ModelService and ModelItem and Sequence and Activity and ActivityBuilder.  I have been looking at MSN documentation to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Found my answer :

  IEnumerable<ModelItem> xyz = modelService.Find(modelService.Root, typeof(Activity));
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/124c9199-c23c-469c-93c5-309f097dc92e/how-to-get-modelitem-collection-from-the-workflowdesigner